# JavaFX 2- Implementation of Webengine

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'd like to know what is the implementation of the html/css/js renderering engine of the new JavaFX 2?

Is it a new implementation or a fork/reuse of a solution such as gecko/webkit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using webkit for embedded HTML:
http://javafx.com/features/